# implementing multi-threaded server with ZeroMQ

Tags: python, multithreading, zeromq

I have a scenario where i have clients in .net that needs to connect to a python server that creates a thread for each accepted client.
Server and client then send AND recieve data between them until the client disconnects and the specific client thread is closed.

Does this scenario fits ZeroMQ and if so, what patterns should i use to implement this scenario? (socket types etc.)

Comment: Thread per client doesn't sound good, especially if you take into consideration what Python does to simulate threads. Have you gone through the ZMQ guide?

Comment: Yes, i read the guide (at least most of it), and i know threads are not a good practice thing in zeromq but my server needs to open a socket for each client to a 3rd party service that has a proprietry protocol and sdk.

Comment: So why not use regular sockets? What would you achieve by using ZMQ here? It looks like you don't need disconnected-tcp approach ZMQ offers..

Comment: i thought it'll save me writing all the send/receive logic for bridging python/.net strings and also partial message arrival.

Comment: Is the communication between client and server synchronous or asynchronous? If it's synchronous, give it a try with `REQ` - `REP` socket pairs.

Comment: I though about REQ-REP but it only allow sending one msg and then returning a reply for it. while i need a continues flow of messages from the server to the client and from the client to the servers without any need for reply more like two way streaming

Answer (score 1):

Whether it works with ZMQ or not depends on how you intend to handle the sockets and threading on your server. It's entirely unclear whether you intend the server threads to handle the ZMQ communication, or if all of the ZMQ communication happens in a single thread, and the other thread-per-process communicates back to the main thread for ZMQ to send back to the client. The latter scenario would be the "ZMQ way", the former requires a few more hoops to work correctly.

If you want all ZMQ communication to happen in a single thread, then you just need to keep track of new clients as they connect, spin up a thread and the communication with that thread (which could happen over a *separate* pair of ZMQ sockets if you like), and then as the clients disconnect, spin down the thread.  Fairly straight forward as an architecture.

If you'd prefer to have each thread handle ZMQ communication back to its client, things get a little hairy.  You *cannot* have a single socket on the server be available to all threads, for each to use to communicate back to its client simultaneously.  ZMQ sockets are not threadsafe.  They are intended to be used by one thread at a time, serially, and it's recommended against passing them around among threads (but can be done by executing a full memory barrier - unsure what it takes to accomplish this in python, if it's possible; it's [suggested here](http://code.saghul.net/index.php/2011/06/25/implementing-a-pubsub-based-application-with-python-and-zeromq/) that the Python GIL *may* accomplish this "for free" - if you choose to rely on that behavior, good luck).

The way to do this the "ZMQ way" would be to accept an incoming connection in the main thread, spin up a thread with a *new* socket (it can use the same ZMQ context, which *is* threadsafe), communicate back to the client which new port is being bound on, have the client disconnect from the main socket and reconnect to the socket in the new thread.  When it disconnects, have that thread terminate.  A bit of a kludge, but workable if that's what you're after.

If either of these methods works for you, I'd use DEALER(client)/ROUTER(server) as your socket types to support fully asynchronous communication.  [Chapter 4 of the guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#reliable-request-reply) gives you some possible communication patterns to start with for various goals.